# RedBeanPHP ... как узнать последнее значение

Tags: mysql, redbeanphp

В таблице есть поле `count`с множеством числовых строк.
Как узнать последнее значение этого поля?

Comment: Что такое последнее значение? В базе данных нет определенного порядка строк.

Comment: @etki последний аутоинкремент

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count FROM table2 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: а как с помощью RedBeanPHP это сделать

Comment: А зачем вы используете RedBeanPHP ?